# How to refetch queries from sibling component with react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js, react-query

I was wondering how to refetch a query from another sibling component with react-query.

Lets say I have Component A

```
 import {useQuery} from "react-query";

 function ComponentA(){

    const getData = async () => data //returns api data

    const {data, refetch} = useQuery(["queryA"], async () => await getData())

    return(

         <div>
           {data}
         </div>

   )}
```

And in Component B

```
 import {useQuery, QueryClient} from "react-query";

 function ComponentB(){

    const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            staleTime: Infinity,
        },
    },
})

const refreshQueryFromComponentA = async () => {
     await queryClient.refetchQueries(["queryA"], { active: true })
}

    return(

         <div>
           <button onClick={refreshQueryFromComponentA}/>
         </div>

   )}
```

And in Page.js

```
 import ComponentA from "./componentA";
 import ComponentB from "./componentB";

 function Page(){

    return(

         <div>
           <ComponentA/>
           <ComponentB/>
         </div>

   )}
```

When I call the refreshQueryFromComponentA function in ComponentB I do not see the query refresh in ComponentA or a new call to the backend in the network tab. I also use the correct query-key but I am only able to refetch the query in ComponentA with the refetch() function which comes from the useQuery function.

I think it's possible what I'm trying to do, since react-query uses context and should be available throughout the whole application. But maybe I'm using the wrong method or misinterpreted it.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 3):

There needs to be one QueryClient at the top of your app. The QueryClient holds the queryCache, which stores your data. If you create a new one in componentB, it won’t share anything with componentA. Also, make sure to add it to the QueryClientProvider and retrieve it via `useQueryClient()`. The client also needs to be stable, so don’t create a new one each render. This is from the first page of the docs:

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query'
2 
3 const queryClient = new QueryClient()
4 
5 export default function App() {
6   return (
7     <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
8       <Example />
9     </QueryClientProvider>
10   )
11 }
```

Comment: Ah my apologies I have one queryClient in my toplevel app.js.
I just used this as a trivial example.

 But  I do see where I"m making a mistake, by creating a new queryClient inside ComponentB which indeed wont share any data with componentA.
I need to find the correct way to access the queryClient methods from the toplevel QueryClientProvider inside my ComponentB. 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the correct way would be `useQueryClient()`

Comment: Thanks, didnt even know how I missed this 